# How do I fix this error "an error occurred while trying to determine whether " " is a function name"

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I'm trying to make a stand alone application for computers without matlab. I'm using the deploytool and when I try to test the application I get this error an "error occurred while trying to determine whether "fn" is a function name", where fn is just a function name in the program. If I comment out the troublesome function it will error to another function.

I've looked online and there is no addPath in my code.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Any chance you could post a [mre]? `deploytool` is quite a complex system with various things that could go wrong.